# Is this a coleus plant?

Tags: identification

I was in Mexico and saw this plant which looks like a coleus due to the mottled scalloped leaves but it is almost four feet tall.  The coleus I am used to are about six inches tall.  What is this plant?
[image: oversized coleus]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *Acalypha wilkesiana*, a member of the family Euphorbiaceae. Sometimes called Copperleaf, it is a hardy, attractive and commonly grown plant in tropical gardens. There are numerous and quite variable forms and cultivars.

https://florafaunaweb.nparks.gov.sg/Special-Pages/plant-detail.aspx?id=1593